# Hadoop `Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain`

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

My use case is to upload files from onpremise Hadoop cluster to AWS S3.  Before achieving it, i tried to do simple `ls` command to see bucket contents from Hadoop.

Before running any command I exported the keys something like this

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<AcessKeyId>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secretekey>
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=<sessiontoken>
```

I was able to see the bucket contents if I use the following command

`aws s3api list-objects --bucket <bucket_name>`

However, when I make use of the following command

```
hadoop fs -Dfs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider="org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider" -Dfs.s3.access.key="<Access key>" -Dfs.s3.secret.key="<Aws access key>" -Dfs.s3a.session.token="<session_token>" -libjars <path to hadoop-aws.jar file> -ls s3a://<bucket_name>/
```

I am getting the following error

`AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain`

My question is even though I am providing `aws credentials` both as environment variables, as well as in the command using `-Dfs.s3.access.key` why am I seeing the `AmazonClientException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider` option and retry. If unspecified then the default list of credential provider classes is queried in sequence (see [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authenticating_with_S3)).

Comment: According to the docs I understand that it will go through default provider classes. However, I am getting the same `AmazonClientException` when I remove the `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider`. I am using the following version `Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.11`.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod, I was able to figure it out, I was not consistent with `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider`  I changed the occurrences of `fs.s3` to `fs.s3a`